# jinja2 - TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I wish to display the data retrieved from SQLite onto webpage. The display layout is a table. But I received below comments:

**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError**
*jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.*

I m new to coding and may I seek help from you? Many thanks.

---

```
Welcome {{username}}, your schedule is as follows.

<tbale id="myTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" onclick="tester()"></table>

    <script> 
    var staff; 
    for (var j=0; j < 1000: j++) {
        staff = {
             {% for key,user in df_dict.items()%}
            department: "{{user.workingdept}}" + j,
            staffid: "{{user.staffid}}" + j,
            staffname: "{{user.staffname}}" + j,
            rank: "{{user.rank}}" + j,
            shift: "{{user.shift}}" + j,
        {% endfor%} 
        };      

        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(j);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(2);

        cell1.innerHTML = staff.department,
        cell2.innerHTML = staff.staffid,
        cell3.innerHTML = staff.staffname,
        cell4.innerHTML = staff.rank,
        cell5.innerHTML = staff.shift;
<br>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: The `<script>` tag is never closed.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 (Your backend templating engine) requires a space character between opening-/closing-indicator and your actual command.

The error is about the "endfor" command not being found. You can solve this problem by correcting your syntax in the following way:

```
{% endfor%}  becomes  {% endfor %}
```

Even though this answers your question, you will run into more errors with your code. A few examples of what should be fixed:

- Your table opening tag is misspelled (tbale).
- You are missing a few HTML tags for your page to be valid or have them wrongly placed.
- You are defining "var cell1" (JavaScript) multiple times.